# Пусть будет всем нам хорошо (—) / И в добрый час, и в добрый час

Tags: тире

Как правильно оформить этот фрагмент песни «Давай, дружок, на посошок»?

> Пусть будет всем нам хорошо — / И в добрый час, и в добрый час.

> Пусть будет всем нам хорошо / И в добрый час, и в добрый час.